# Flex4 external style sheets PropertyReference

Tags: css, apache-flex, flex4, stylesheet

I'm trying to declare a style property to be the value of some variable.  This is done easily enough within a component with a call to 'PropertyReference'.  Ex:

```
<fx:Style>
  ...
  s|TextInput {
    color: PropertyReference("some.other.package.MyClass.colorVariable");
  }
</fx:Style>
```

However, I'm trying to do this in an external stylesheet and load it into the `<s:Application>` top-level component with `<fx:Style source="myStyles.css"/>`.  This won't compile though.  It seems that the use of PropertyReference itself is OK, but it's like it can't resolve the path to the variable I want to use.

Anybody know how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

As you include your css using `<fx:Style source=""/>`, it must contains CSS only.
Since you need to add programmatic code in your CSS, you may try [loading your style sheet at run time](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f8c.html)

Comment: I don't know if that is true, because within the same source file, I have several rules the use set the skin for a component.  For example, `.buttonPanel { skinClass: ClassReference("package.panel.ButtonPanelSkin"); }` and this works just fine (although once in a while it doesn't).  Unless this is somehow incidental, I only have consistent problems with `PropertyReference`.